# Win32 API to modify network interface properties

Tags: c++, winapi, networking, network-interface, setupapi

I was unable to find a Win32 API to modify network interface properties. By "network interface properties" I mean properties, which can be set using the "network connections" panel in the System control panel manually or using "netsh interface" from the command line.

In particular, I want to modify:

- The network connection name (e.g. "Local Area Connection #2"
- The IPv4 network interface metric (which is "automatic" by default)

To identify the network adapter, I have a device instance ID of the PnP device manager (e.g. "ROOT\NET\0000"). I also have an instance of a SetupAPI SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure. I can probably also query the NetCfgInstanceId using SetupAPI.

Is there a Win32 API which does what I want? I don't want to use WMI. Target platforms are Windows 7 x64 or newer.

Comment: "I don't want to use WMI." -- why not? That would be the obvious way to solve this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not guaranteed that the WMI services are running

Comment: You can use [`SetUpInterfaceEntry()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-setipinterfaceentry) to mess with the metric.  Not sure about changing the friendly name though...

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**
Try using [INetworkConnection::Rename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365099(v=vs.85).aspx). In order to get the connection you want, you have to use [INetSharingManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365960(v=vs.85).aspx) to enumerate all connections.
Do an iteration to find the one you need to change.